# How to use mongoDB $sum in @Query

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new user of mongoDB, I have create an application with spring boot/mySql and I want replace database sql to mongoDB.

I did change all things necessary for example, annotations, relations etc ... but I have a problem with request I don't know the similar syntax of @Query in mongoDb.

this my request with sql:

```
// this calculate the sum of all distance in walk's document
@Query("select sum(distance) from Walk")
public Double sumDistance();
```

I did read mongoDB aggregate and I know how to use it in console windows with command

```
$ mongo
$ db.walk.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$dateWalk",Count:{$sum:"$distance"}}}])
```

but, I want use $sum in my program java not in console.

So please, I need your help about the syntax similar to this with mongoDB

```
// this calculate the sum of all distance in walk's document
@Query("select sum(distance) from Walk")
public Double sumDistance();
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: This examples will help you. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples In case you are wondering here are the query methods supported in mongo db http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Comment: thanks @Veeram, your answer works for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a [custom Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) that would implement the aggregation.

**Examples**:

- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/04/data-aggregation-spring-data-mongodb-spring-boot.html
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/mongodb/aggregation/src/main/java/example/springdata/mongodb/aggregation/OrderRepositoryImpl.java